# Getting thumbnail URI from a new video added to MediaStore

Tags: android, video, thumbnails, mediastore

I'm recording video with my app and on stop the video is added to Android **MediaStore** in order to appear in the video gallery.
I need to get the **thumbnail URI** as soon the video is added to the gallery.
How I can do this ?
Below, the code I'm using to add the video to gallery:

```
private void addVideoGallery() {

long dateTaken=System.currentTimeMillis();
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(outputfilename));
int duration = mp.getDuration();
mp.release();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, outputfilename);
values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN, dateTaken);
values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION, duration);
ContentResolver resolver = MainActivity.this.getContentResolver();
resolver.insert(Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```

}